# How to solve the error "type or namespace name could not be found" on AssetBundle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a project in Visual Studio 2019 integrated with Unity.
When trying to use an asset bundle, i get the error `type or namespace name could not be found`

The line that gives me the error is

`AssetBundle assetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromStream(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(typeof(Main), "Name"));`

Documentation on asset bundles says that this line should work ok, there doesn't seem to be a reference issue either.

My Unity reference is `using UnityEngine;`

I'm wondering if I'm missing a step or I'm using the line in a wrong way to use asset bundles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was missing a reference.

`using UnityEngine.AssetBundleModule;`

Comment: Thanks for this,  For future reference the dll is UnityEngine.AssetBundleModule.dll